# Adding file-user in shell-script

Tags: shell-script, shell, users

I'm trying to add users with code like this:

```bash
asadmin start-domain

asadmin create-file-user --groups=user --target=server-config -authrealmname=file --passwordfile=password.txt a

asadmin create-file-user --groups=user --target=server-config --authrealmname=file --passwordfile=password.txt b

asadmin create-file-user --groups=admin --target=server-config --authrealmname=file --passwordfile=password.txt c

asadmin stop-domain
```

And I get:

```
remote failure: Adding User a to file realm file failed.  User a already exists.
User a already exists.
```

But no users exist. What am I doing wrong?

Another question: is it possible to run sh script after deployment in InteliJ, and if yes how to do it?

Comment: I have another question: is it possible to run sh script after deployment in intelij? And if yes how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to U&L. If you have something to add to the question (someone asks for more info or clarification, you have further questions etc.) please don't use comments. Instead [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736309/edit) your question. This way everything relevant is readily available. I added this question now, it'll come visible when another community member approves my edit. It's a good idea to take the [Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the Asking- and Answering-sections in the [Help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get a handle on how SE sites work.